# MediaWiki - sort simple list

Tags: mediawiki

I have a basic MediaWiki installation with several categories (which is sorted automatically). In each category I have several links to articles. These links are listed in a simple star (*) list, which is not sorted automatically.

I know I can use a table but 1) that seems counter-intuitive to me, 2) I want the list of articles to be sorted automatically rather than having a interactive table where the user has to sort manually and 3) I want a clean, easy list without borders, preferably with that preceding circle. I could also use sub-categories, but because I'm a weird duck (lazy or maybe just adamant to solve this using lists as I feel this should be doable) I want to explore this route first.

Is there a somewhat easy solution for this? Either with css, js, html(?), extension or other? I have extremely little experience in this matter and would have to ask that any answers is given in layman's term (e.g. solution/step-by-step guide on silver platter, if at all possible).

What I want is for:

```
* [[Example article 1]]
* [[Article 2]]
* [[Etc]]
```

To become:

- Article 2
- Etc
- Example article 1

Instead of:

- Example article 1
- Article 2
- Etc

Comment: It seems to me that you misuse categories. If you add `[[Category:Some category]]` to some pages, the page *Category:Some category* will contain an ordered list of those pages,

Comment: I realize that (hence my comment on "sub-categories" (category in category, I guess)) and that might even be best practice, I don't know. I would still like to be able to automatically sort a simple list, though, if possible. If for no other reason, then because my wiki is already set up impractical and I would like to avoid converting all the relevant pages to categories... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to sort a simple list server-side, install *[Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto)*, create *Module:Utils* containing

```
return {
    sort = function (frame)
        local trim = mw.text.trim
        -- Since frame.args is not a real table, it has to be copied:
        local args = {}
        for _, arg in ipairs (frame.args) do
            args [#args + 1] = trim (arg)
        end
        table.sort (args)
        return table.concat (args, '\n')
    end
}
```

and invoke the `sort` function from the wikitext like this:

```
{{#invoke:Utils|sort
| * 2. Second
| * 1. First
| * 3. Third
}}
```

If you want to sort a table client-side, add `sortable` class to it, as described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Sorting#Sorting_rows_of_a_table).